# Adding a 'None' or 'All' Option to JavaFx ComboBox

Tags: javafx-2

I was wondering how I might go about adding a 'None' or 'All' option to a JavaFx combobox control.  My current combobox is backed by a list of complex objects, but just displays the name of he object.  I was hoping to avoid have to create a Dummy object with the name "None" or "All".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `promptText` property, inherited from class `javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase`.